# Conversion tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, history-tracking, conversion

I am trying to set up the conversion tracking using Javascript for my website.

I arrive at the part where it's asking about:

[image]

I wanted to ask which script that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need specific help setting up conversion tracking in your website, and the resources on the link below aren't helpful, then I recommend reaching out to Salesforce support for further information.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_conversion_pages.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the comment you're looking at marks the beginning of the conversion tracking script.  The script is everything below that line.  (Yeah, I read it wrong the first time too!)

```
<!-- ExactTarget Conversion Tracking Script Here-->

**** THIS IS THE CONVERSION TRACKING SCRIPT: ****
<script language="javascript">//Set the following parameters for your conversion parameters
    var convid = "1";
    var displayorder = "1";
    var linkalias = "My Link Name";
    var dataset = "<data amt=\"1\" unit=\"Downloads\" accumulate=\"true\" />";
    //For additional datasets, simply add them to the concatenation:
    //dataset=dataset+"<data amt=\"500.00\" unit=\"Dollars\" accumulate=\"true\">
    //Do not change anything below
    function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
        var today = new Date();
        var expire = new Date();
        if (nDays == null || nDays == 0) nDays = 1;
            expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + "; expires=" +
            expire.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
        }

    function getCookie(cookiename) {
        if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
            startC = document.cookie.indexOf(cookiename + "=");
            if (startC != -1) {
                startC += cookiename.length + 1;
                endC = document.cookie.indexOf(";", startC);
                if (endC == -1) endC = document.cookie.length;
                    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(startC, endC));
                }
            }
        return null;
    }
    var jobid = getCookie("JobID");
    var emailaddr = getCookie("EmailAddr_");
    var subid = getCookie("SubscriberID");
    var listid = getCookie("ListID");
    var batchid = getCookie("BatchID");
    var urlid = getCookie("UrlID");
    var memberid = getCookie("MemberID");
</script>
```